# How can I merge pictures Android?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 pictures, one is a background and the other is a complete picture.

I want to create one image from both of them as if one is above the other and save them on your cell phone as one image

Which JAVA library should I study and research?

I would be happy if you would refer me to the same library I develop in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, this is what you have to do:

Folder drawable -> new -> drawable resource file -> choose the name of the file and click ok

and this is what you get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
   

</selector>
```

Inside the tags `selector` put the tag `<layer-list>` (remember to close the tag)  and inside the `layer-list` put the tag `<item>`

your result can be this for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
            </item>
            <item>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
        </item>
</selector>
```

Now you can customize your 2 items, if you want to put an image inside your item you can write your code like this:

```
<item
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"
    android:width="96dp"
    android:height="96dp"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

if you want to put a shape of an object like a rectangle you can write your code like this:

```
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="#000000" />
        <size
            android:width="1080px"
            android:height="1920px" />
        <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Now you have your image composed with 2 images (or other things) and if you want to use it you can just call `android:background="@drawable/YOUR_FILE_NAME"` inside your `layout_activity.xml` for example

with this informations I think you can solve your problem, cya :)